# Fee based on checkout radio buttons choice in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In WooCommerce checkout I have successfully added custom radio buttons. I want to set a dynamic fee based on the customer choice. Customer can select an option from the custom radio buttons.

Here is my code:

```
// Output the Custom field in check out
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'checkout_radio_choice', 10,2);
function checkout_radio_choice(){
    ?>
    <label for="custom_field">

        <input type="radio" name="custom_field" checked="checked" value="option0">DECLINED  <br />
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field" value="option1">SIGNATURE <br />
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field" value="option2">INSURANCE<br />
    </label> <br />
    <?php
}

// Stores the custom field value in Cart object
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_product_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['custom_field'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ 'custom_field' ] = $_REQUEST['custom_field'];
        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
        WC()->session->set( 'my_order_data', $_REQUEST['custom_field'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Outuput custom Item value in Cart and Checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'output_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
 function output_custom_product_field_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    if( isset( $cart_item['custom_field'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Custom Item', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => $cart_item['custom_field'],
            'display'   => $cart_item['custom_field'],
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}

// Dynamic fee
function WPE_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );

    if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
        $fee = 4;
    }
    elseif ( "option_2" == $radio ) {
        $fee = ( ( wc_prices_include_tax() ? $cart->get_cart_contents_total() + $cart->get_cart_contents_tax() : $cart->get_cart_contents_total() ) * 0.027 + 4.00 );
    }

    $cart->add_fee( __('Protection', 'woocommerce'), $fee );-
}
```

But something is wrong with the "`WPE_checkout_radio_choice_fee()`" function, as it doesn't work.

How to I add a dynamic fee based on checkout radio buttons choice in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

The actions hooks `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` and `woocommerce_get_item_data` are used for product custom fields, but not for checkout custom fields.

Your case requires Ajax to pass the selected "protection choice" to `WC_Session` solving your issue.

```
// Output the Custom field in check out
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'checkout_radio_choice', 10,2);
function checkout_radio_choice(){
    $input_key = 'protection_choice';
    $value     = WC()->session->get($input_key);
    $options   = array(
        __("DECLINED", "woocommerce"),
        __("SIGNATURE", "woocommerce"),
        __("INSURANCE", "woocommerce"),
    );

    echo '<p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="'.$input_key.'_field"><label for="'.$input_key.'">
        <input type="radio" name="'.$input_key.'" value="" checked="checked"> '.__("DECLINED", "woocommerce").'<br />
        <input type="radio" name="'.$input_key.'" value="signature"> '.__("SIGNATURE", "woocommerce").'<br />
        <input type="radio" name="'.$input_key.'" value="insurance"> '.__("INSURANCE", "woocommerce").'<br />
    </label></p>';
}

// The jQuery Ajax request (client side)
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_custom_jquery_script' );
function checkout_custom_jquery_script() {
    // Only checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    $session_key = 'protection_choice';

    // Remove "options_choice" custom WC session on load
    if( WC()->session->get($session_key) ){
        WC()->session->__unset($session_key);
    }
    // jQuery Ajax code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var a = 'input[name=<?php echo $session_key; ?>]';

        $('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name=<?php echo $session_key; ?>]', function(){
            var choice = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'get_<?php echo $session_key; ?>',
                    'the_choice': choice,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(response); // For testing, to be removed.
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver (server side)
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_protection_choice', 'get_checkout_protection_choice' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_protection_choice', 'get_checkout_protection_choice' );
function get_checkout_protection_choice() {
    $session_key = 'protection_choice';

    if ( isset($_POST['the_choice']) ){
        WC()->session->set( $session_key, esc_attr( $_POST['the_choice'] ) );
        echo $_POST['the_choice'];
    }
    die();
}

// Add a custom fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'chosen_custom_fee', 20, 1 );
function chosen_custom_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( $choice = WC()->session->get('protection_choice') ) {
        if ( "signature" === $choice ) {
            $fee = 4.00;
        }
        elseif ( "insurance" === $choice ) {
            $subtotal_excl_tax = (float) $cart->get_cart_contents_total();
            $subtotal_incl_tax = $subtotal_excl_tax + (float) $cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
            $fee = ( wc_prices_include_tax() ? $subtotal_incl_tax : $subtotal_excl_tax ) * 0.027 + 4.00;
        }

        $cart->add_fee( __("Protection", "woocommerce"), $fee );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thanks for your answer,(I was hoping you would respond) I have already achieved the function of adding it as a fee , for reasons beyond my control i have been given 2 options a:it must be recorded as a product or b: leave it as a fee and have it print a message in the customer order notes box option0- customer declined option1 thank you for selecting signature confirmation option2 thank you for selecting insurance and signature ...the reason for this is we are using an api to feed all our venue orders to our shipping portal , said api doesn't pickup the fees and refuse to help